# Flutter segmentation "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)" error

Tags: android, flutter, memory, segmentation-fault

I have encountered a problem in my Android App. When I press button to update user my app crashes and gives this error:

```
F/libc    (16948): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x5f in tid 16992 (1.ui), pid 16948 (mple.resto_flow)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/m53xnsxx/m53x:13/TP1A.220624.014/M536BXXU4CWHA:user/release-keys'
Revision: '6'
ABI: 'arm64'
Processor: '6'
Timestamp: 2023-11-05 18:32:57.932770525+0200
Process uptime: 10s
Cmdline: com.example.resto_flow
pid: 16948, tid: 16992, name: 1.ui  >>> com.example.resto_flow <<<
uid: 10283
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x000000000000005f
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  b400006ff412a650  x1  0000000000000000  x2  0000000000000005  x3  0000000000000001
    x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000000  x7  0000000000000000
    x8  0000000000000000  x9  000000700c8f1320  x10 b400006ff412a640  x11 0000000000000001
    x12 0000000000000034  x13 0000000000000004  x14 0000000000000000  x15 0008000000000000
    x16 000000700c819860  x17 0000007129bc0620  x18 0000007009314000  x19 b400006ff412a630
    x20 000000700c9f9380  x21 b400006ff3f99000  x22 b400006ff412a650  x23 0000000000000000
    x24 000000700c7a9f98  x25 0000006e069fdca1  x26 000000700c8e4000  x27 b4000070102cb800
    x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000000000000002
    lr  000000700c4d18dc  sp  000000700c9f84c0  pc  000000700c4d18e8  pst 0000000080001000
```

Here is the code of page where the button is pressed and user must be updated:

```
import 'package:accordion/accordion.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:resto_flow/blocs/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:resto_flow/repositories/user_repository.dart';
import 'package:resto_flow/widgets/auth/pass_text_field.dart';

import '../blocs/events/auth_event.dart';
import '../generated/l10n.dart';
import '../blocs/states/auth_state.dart';
import '../widgets/my_themed_alert.dart';
import '../widgets/settings_tile.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  late final TextEditingController _firstNameController;
  late final TextEditingController _lastNameController;
  late final TextEditingController _emailController;
  late final TextEditingController _newPasswordController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firstNameController = TextEditingController();
    _lastNameController = TextEditingController();
    _emailController = TextEditingController();
    _newPasswordController = TextEditingController();

    _firstNameController.text = UserRepository.currentUser?.firstName ?? "";
    _lastNameController.text = UserRepository.currentUser?.lastName ?? "";
    _emailController.text = UserRepository.currentUser?.email ?? "";
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _firstNameController.dispose();
    _lastNameController.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _newPasswordController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tilesBackgroundColor =
        Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor.withRed(100);

    return BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthAuthenticated) {
          final user = state.user;
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(
                  "${S.current.hello} ${user.firstName.isNotEmpty ? user.firstName : S.current.stranger}"),
              actions: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      user.bonusScore.toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    const Icon(Icons.monetization_on, color: Colors.yellow),
                  ],
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (ctx) {
                        return MyThemedAlert(
                          title: Text(S.current.confirm_log_out),
                          content: Text(S.current.want_to_log_out),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            TextButton(
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                                  Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: Text(S.current.cancel),
                            ),
                            TextButton(
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                                  Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                context.read<AuthBloc>().add(
                                      AuthSignOutEvent(),
                                    );
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              child: Text(S.current.log_out),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
                )
              ],
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          SettingsTile(
                            width: 220,
                            title: Text(S.current.email),
                            trailing: Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller: _emailController,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: S.current.email,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SettingsTile(
                            width: 220,
                            title: Text(S.current.firstname),
                            trailing: Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller: _firstNameController,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: S.current.firstname,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SettingsTile(
                            width: 220,
                            title: Text(S.current.lastname),
                            trailing: Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller: _lastNameController,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: S.current.lastname,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Accordion(
                            paddingListHorizontal: 0,
                            contentBorderColor: tilesBackgroundColor,
                            disableScrolling: true,
                            children: [
                              AccordionSection(
                                headerPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                headerBackgroundColor: tilesBackgroundColor,
                                headerBorderRadius: 10,
                                contentBorderRadius: 10,
                                contentVerticalPadding: 30,
                                contentBackgroundColor: tilesBackgroundColor,
                                header: Text(S.current.password),
                                content: SettingsTile(
                                  trailing: Expanded(
                                    child: PasswordTextField(
                                      passController: _newPasswordController,
                                      titleText: S.current.new_password,
                                      allowEmpty: true,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  showDivider: false,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        String newPassword = "";
                        if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
                          newPassword = _newPasswordController.text.trim();
                          final editedFirstName =
                              _firstNameController.text.trim();
                          final editedLastName =
                              _lastNameController.text.trim();
                          final editedEmail = _emailController.text.trim();

                          context.read<AuthBloc>().add(
                                AuthUpdateUserEvent(
                                  user: user.copyWith(
                                    firstName: editedFirstName,
                                    lastName: editedLastName,
                                    email: editedEmail,
                                    password: newPassword.isEmpty
                                        ? null
                                        : newPassword,
                                  ),
                                  email: user.email,
                                ),
                              );
                        }
                      },
                      child: const Text('Save Changes'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          context.read<AuthBloc>().add(AuthWantToLogInEvent());
        }
        return Center(
          child:
              CircularProgressIndicator(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Please, let me know if you need more details about the problem or you have some possible solutions. Thank you!

I've tried initializing textEditingControllers in many ways, using expanded for my widgets differently, but nothing helps.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm getting the same error too. @freaklessgamer